# What is the high-level between a browser and a tab?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

Working on a firefox extension I eventually hit upon being able to grab a [`selectedBrowser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#p-selectedBrowser) or a [`selectedTab`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#p-selectedTab) while using a `tabbrowser`.

Not knowing the high level definition of the two items (a [`tab`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tab) has a document? Then why doesn't `tab` have a browser property?)

Similarly, I have found myself wondering, if associating properties to what a user is currently doing, if I would be better off using `gBrowser.selectedBrowser.MYSPECIALPROPERTY` vs `gBrowser.selectedTab.MYSPECIALPROPERTY`.

I usually needed a `browser` both because it had the methods I wanted to work with and because I found it easier to grab Browsers and muck with them than to grab Tabs and much with them, but I don't like the idea of prefering one over the other without a full understanding of why.

I would am also found myself wondering how I can get from a `selectedBrowser` to a `selectedTab` or vice versa, assuming at least one of those transitions even makes sense.

These questions are somewhat separable, but I am missing some key high-level understanding so I'm not sure I'd be able to ask one of these questions and get an answer that cleared up my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<tabbrowser>` is a specialized version of [`<tabbox>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbox). Normally, a `<tabbox>` is a collection of tabs and the associated tab panels. Here the tab is actually a tab header that you click on to switch to a particular tab, the tab panel is what is being displayed then (it's the container for tab content). There is no direct mapping between tabs and tab panels, they simply happen to have the same index in their respective container node. At least that's the general idea that is slightly complicated by the fact that tabs can be linked to a particular panel explicitly via [`linkedpanel` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tab#a-linkedpanel).

Now a `<tabbrowser>` has a [`<browser>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/browser) element in each of its tab panels. But it uses the same `<tab>` elements that you would have in a regular `<tabbox>` as well. Since both `<tab>` and `<browser>` can be used outside of `<tabbrowser>` you will not find any special API on them. That kind of API is only available in `<tabbrowser>`.

To get a browser for a particular tab header you can use [`tabbrowser.getBrowserForTab()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#m-getBrowserForTab). Going the other way round is more complicated (and usually unnecessary). If you really need it, you can use [`tabbrowser.getBrowserIndexForDocument()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#m-getBrowserIndexForDocument) to get the index of the browser. You can then get the corresponding tab via [`tabbrowser.tabs.getItemAtIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabs#m-getItemAtIndex).

Just to repeat this: usually you will want to work with the `<browser>` elements. There is little reason to look at tab headers (unless you want to reorder them or something like that).